# Static menu in HTML / CSS when scrolling down?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the horizontal and main menu of my web page not be displaced by scrolling down the contents of the web? I think it should be with the position: fixed tag so that it remains static and does not change regardless of the dimensions of the body of the page but I can not.

The menu in question is this and thus remains with its respective CSS of the menu that is this:

```
#menu ul
{   margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 8px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#menu ul li a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 25px 8px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #91B0AF;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 25px 8px;
}
```

If I put the position fixed in the complete div of the menu, the thing stays like this, it gets mismatched according to the background image and it is aligned to the left: S

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe want to provide a code snippet or a link to a pen/fiddle.

Comment: Please post your HTML code or link to a fiddle

Comment: what do you mean by downloading scroll? It's confusing

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y > 0) {
        $('#header').addClass('fixedPosition');
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('fixedPosition');

    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.home {
    min-height:400px;
}
#header-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #E0E0E1;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#header p {
    color: #FFF;
}
#header h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
#header h1 a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header h1 a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

ul {
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

.fixedPosition {
    position:fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-center">
        <ul>
          <li><a>HOME</a></li>
          <li><a>WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Try this. See whether it is match with your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Add below styles to complete div of the main menu.

```
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
text-align:center;
```

This code works for you. Try it.
let me know if there any problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but it still does not work well

Comment: I made another answer.Try it

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to hide it that means on scrolling you want it to move with the page if that is the case you can go with

```
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
```

but if you want it to br fixed trying applying this code on #menu. I suppose it is a div element.

```
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
```

if it is not working share a screenshot for us to check what the issue is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) { // this refers to window
        position:fixed;
    }
});
```